# Is $e^{-\gamma}$ the limit of this expression involving Harmonic numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

Is it known (and true) that
$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{j=0}^N (-1)^{N-j} {N \choose j} (j/N)^{NH_N} = e^{-\gamma} $$
where $H_N$ is the Nth Harmonic number ?

The summation is the probability that the waiting time for a complete collection in the coupon collector problem  is less than or equal to its expectation. (Standard coupon collector problem, i.e. uniform distribution).

Rather than $e^{-\gamma}$ , it seems that limit is
$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}(1-e^{-H_N})^{N} = e^{-e^{-\gamma}} $$ 
i.e. 0.57037 instead of 0.56146.

Comment: We can try to evaluate $\sum_{j=0}^N (-1)^{j}  {N \choose j} (1-j/N)^{N H_N}$ by expanding $(1-j/N)^{N H_N} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {N H_N \choose k} (-j/N)^k$, invert the two sums to get $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {N H_N \choose k} (-1/N)^k \sum_{j=0}^N (-1)^j  {N \choose j} j^k$ and use a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Series_involving_binomial_coefficients) for $\sum_{j=0}^N (-1)^{j}  {N \choose j} j^k$

Comment: Using the Stirling approximation, no it diverges.

Comment: Striling numbers 2nd order have integer parameters, it is not the case there.

Comment: Last formula you suggest is null for k<N, except for few values above N, no general formula exists.

Comment: to see the convergence:

Comment: double myexpression (unsigned int N) {
gsl_sf_result H;
unsigned int j;
double T = 0.0; double H_N=0.0; unsigned int b; for (b=1;b<=N;b=b+1)  H_N+=1.0/b;
for (j=0;j<=N;j++) { gsl_sf_choose_e (N,j,&H); T+=pow(-1,N-j)* (double) H.val * pow((double)j/(double)N,H_N*N); }
return T ;
}